# Ruby Exceptions in a loop

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script that loops through a list of shortened urls (around 2,000 - 3,000 at a time). At the moment everything is peachy until a hit a url that is malformed, timedout etc. When an error occurs my script dies. How can I setup my loop to skip to the next record when/if such an error occurs.

my loop looks like this:

```
blah.foo do |barurl|
  mymethod(barurl)
```

my mymethod looks like this:

```
def mymethod(barurl)
  begin
    stuff
    ...
    return expandedurl
  rescue
    return "Problem expanding link"
  end
end
```

Should my begin/end logic be wrapped around my loop instead of the method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you need to skip the malformed url, you should use the exception message to control the loop

```
blah.foo do |barurl|
  begin
    mymethod(barurl)
  rescue YourTypeOfException
    next
  end
end
```

and inside the method raise the exception

```
def mymethod(barurl)
  stuff
  ...
  raise YourTypeOfException, "this url is not valid"
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the existing answers unsatisfying, and reading [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.com/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html) suggests to me that the OP had something more like the example suggested there in mind:

```
[0, 1, 2].map do |i|
  10 / i
rescue ZeroDivisionError
  nil
end
#=> [nil, 10, 5]
```

The docs specifically note that a rescue block permits the loop to continue on a caught exception (as indicated by the example).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All your method does is consume the exception and return *another* arbitrary object in order to indicate an error.

Your method shouldn't handle its own exceptional conditions. It is just rude on its part to make assumptions about how the caller will react.

```
blah.foo do |url|
  begin
    my_method url
  rescue
    next
  end
end
```

Whether to skip to the next URL or print a message is not a decision the method should be making. Its only concern should be working with the URL.

With that said, you should simply let it propagate and only rescue from it when you can actually deal with it. Don't rescue from a `TimeoutError` if all you can do is return `:timeout`.

Do rescue when you need to clean up resources or simply let the user know an error occurred.

Also, rescuing from every possible error just to make them go away is a nice way to introduce bugs. Be as specific as possible.

Comment: hmm - thanks for the answer Matheus - but... I think your answer contradicts both Dave and keymone no? Perhaps I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 1):

having exception handling within your method is proper way of doing it, so your implementation is fine

i can only point some ruby sytax sugar to you:

```
def some_method
  # here goes the code
rescue Exception => e
  # here goes specific exception/error handling
rescue
  # here goes error handling (not Exception handling though!)
else
  # do this block when no exceptions are raised
ensure
  # do this every time
end
```

btw you don't need `return` statements, last value of code block is always returned implicitly

ah i guess i misread your question in the "how to skip next record"

if you want to skip the record *after* current one that was incorrect you would have to return error code from your parsing method and set up skipping within your loop using `break` or `next` keywords

Answer (score 0):

It should be *inside* the loop, so the loop structure isn't exited on an exception. But it looks like it already is--if you're rescuing inside the method that causes the exception, the loop should already continue normally, because it shouldn't be seeing the exception.

Comment: that's what I was thinking Dave - yet my loop is breaking upon seeing the exception. I may need to go back and look at my exception handling.

Comment: @EdBloom Including the exception trace and enough context to make sense of it would allow additional help. Do you act on the return value assuming it's a URL?